# Forcing a format in TFS bug work item

Tags: formatting, tfs-workitem

I know we can customize the TFS work item window to have the tabs we want,
but is it possible to force a format in one of the tabs?
(for example, in "Bug description" I'd like to prevent the tester from writing only 2 words,
or to make it look like a predefined word document they have to fill in, instead of writing free text.)

Comment: I'll set the tester on fire. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for the Description field:
Environment: DEV/QA/PROD
Steps to reproduce:
 1. abcd
 2. abcd
Expected results:
Actual results:

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to enforce a format on a rich text field in TFS. A custom control would be able to validate the contents of itself or another control though, so it would not be impossible to create validation.

Due to the difficulties around distributing and maintaining custom controls, not many shops will take the step to extend TFS in this way. Custom controls must be created for each version of Visual Studio that connects to your TFS and the Web Access interface. They must be upgraded (and sometimes changed considerably) when a new version of TFS is released.

It may be easier to create a report that flags *bad* test cases instead.